# Can I increase the size of my breakers without modifying the wiring?

Tags: heating

I have 10 amp breakers.  When turning on several lights or running several things the breaker trips.

Can I change them to 15amp?  Is that higher or going wrong way?

Read about wire sizes, how is gauge identified?

Comment: Where are you in this universe? What all loads are on each breaker? What size wire is attached to these breakers?

Comment: Of course not.  There was a safety restriction which prohibited the builder from using 15A breakers *in the first place*, or he would've simply done so.  They cost exactly the same.  These aren't tripping to annoy you, they are tripping because you are doing something unreasonable (and don't realize it). The answer is to do a little learning about your electrical "things" - you'll find it's no accident certain combinations cause a trip.  We're happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

**The initial answer is NO - do not "just replace it with a 15 Amp breaker"**

**UNTIL you learn more about the setup.**

Your best source will be whomever installed it in the first place.

Alternatively, you will want to have a qualified electrician take a look and give you an answer that applies directly to you.

Comment: "weak power source"?  You must be thinking in terms of solar or battery systems.  I am thinking OP is not in the United States.

Comment: Yeah, me, too.  By weak power source I was remembering some of the neighborhoods I have seen just over the southern border.  i.e., if it has been split to too many homes or apartments then over time whomever installed it has probably figured out what amount of power each can be allowed before it affects the others.  Weak in this sense would be the overall amp load, which could be "weak" by being fed with regular extension cords like they sometimes do in MX.

Comment: I remember an episode of Green Acres where Lisa had numbers written on the plugs for her appliances and she could only have a total of 7 before the generator would blow up..  Each appliance had a certain number.  Some of those neighborhoods were just like that.  ;-)  Except that it would melt the feedline instead of blowing things up.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the info as to what each one of these circuits has on them, that would help. 
Gosh, it's been a while since I've seen a *"10 amp"* circuit breaker. They are special order, not off the shelf items where I am located.

I installed one once, per request of a building inspector where there was a natural gas type instant hot water heater that required a 120v. circuit to power the temperature controls of it, which had #18 wires in it....

I must admit though, I haven't seen a load center full of 10 amp breakers. That is unbelievable  !

Pictures of the box, please ( for my viewing pleasure, of course !)

Comment: Suspect (as noted in another comment, but never responded to by OP) that this is outside the US. 10A is much more common outside the US - i.e., consider 10A @ 240V ~= 20A @ 120V.